# Can't fetch three fields consistently from some identical webpages

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I've written a script in python to fetch `username`, `followers` and `posts` of certain accounts from instagram. When I run the script I could see that it behaves weirdly. To be clearer - I tried using three accounts and

this is the resuts that I've got:

```
('backstreetboys', '2.2m Followers', '151 Posts')
('akon', '', '')
('louisnpearls', '', '080 posts')
```

What I wish to get:

```
('backstreetboys', '2.2m Followers', '151 Posts')
('akon', '6.4m followers', '1,700 posts')
('louisnpearls', '55.5k followers', '080 posts')
```

Script that I've tried with:

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

urls = [
    'https://www.instagram.com/backstreetboys/',
    'https://www.instagram.com/akon/',
    'https://www.instagram.com/louisnpearls/'
]

def get_instagram_info(url):

    res = requests.get(url,headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"})
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
    username = soup.select_one("meta[property='al:ios:url']").get("content").split("=")[-1]

    try:
        desc = soup.select_one("meta[property='og:description']").get("content")
    except Exception: desc = ""

    try:
        followers = re.findall(r".*(?<=Followers)",desc,re.I)[0]
    except Exception: followers = ""

    try:
        posts = re.findall(r"[^,]+(?<=Posts)",desc,re.I)[0]
    except Exception: posts = "" 

    return username,followers,posts

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for url in urls:
        print(get_instagram_info(url))
```

What possible change should I bring about to let the script fetch the aforementioned fields accordingly using requests?

Comment: I believe the problem is not in the requests since it is able to get atleast some information from the page. It has to do something with the chracter matching in findall of followers and posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the meta description you pulled of akon, the numbers you are pulling don't exist there. Your method probably only works with some accounts, but not others. My method uses json data stored in the page source. Also, I believe there is an Instagram api available if you want to check that out.

## Code

```py
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

urls = [
    'https://www.instagram.com/backstreetboys/',
    'https://www.instagram.com/akon/',
    'https://www.instagram.com/louisnpearls/'
]


def get_instagram_info(url):
    res = requests.get(url, headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0"})
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "lxml")

    script_data = [script.text for script in soup.find_all('script') if script.text[:18] == 'window._sharedData'][0]
    script_json = json.loads(script_data[21:-1])
    username = script_json['entry_data']['ProfilePage'][0]['graphql']['user']['username']
    followers = script_json['entry_data']['ProfilePage'][0]['graphql']['user']['edge_followed_by']['count']
    posts = script_json['entry_data']['ProfilePage'][0]['graphql']['user']['edge_owner_to_timeline_media']['count']
    return username, followers, posts


if __name__ == '__main__':
    for url in urls:
        print(get_instagram_info(url))
```

## Output

```
('backstreetboys', 2279332, 2152)
('akon', 6476386, 1700)
('louisnpearls', 55513, 1080)
```